# How do I put the last 5 images into row of the next line?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Current Situation]

I can't able to stack last 5 objects into rows in next line. I don't know what to do. Please help me.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 10,
      child: ListView(scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal, 
       children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: [
            CategoriesCard(
                (Image.asset(
                  'assets/icons/categoori.png',
                  height: 70,
                  width: 60,
                )),
                'All \nCategories'),
            CategoriesCard(
                (Image.asset(
                  'assets/icons/Electronics.png',
                  height: 70,
                  width: 60,
                )),
                'Electronics \n    Devices'),
            CategoriesCard(
                (Image.asset(
                  'assets/icons/Mens.JPG',
                  height: 70,
                  width: 60,
                )),
                "   Men's \n Fashion"),
            CategoriesCard(
                (Image.asset(
                  'assets/icons/womens.JPG',
                  height: 70,
                  width: 60,
                )),
                " Women's \n Fashion"),
            CategoriesCard(
                (Image.asset(
                  'assets/icons/watch.JPG',
                  height: 70,
                  width: 60,
                )),
                '    Watch & \n   Accessories'),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0)),
            CategoriesCard(
                (Image.asset(
                  'assets/icons/abc.JPG',
                  height: 70,
                  width: 60,
                )),
                '  Home & \n   Lifestyle'),
            CategoriesCard(
                (Image.asset(
                  'assets/icons/health.JPG',
                  height: 70,
                  width: 60,
                )),
                '  Health & \n   Beauty'),
            CategoriesCard(
                (Image.asset(
                  'assets/icons/books.JPG',
                  height: 70,
                  width: 60,
                )),
                '  Books & \n Music'),
            CategoriesCard(
                (Image.asset(
                  'assets/icons/gifts.JPG',
                  height: 70,
                  width: 60,
                )),
                '  Gifts & \n  Cakes'),
            CategoriesCard(
                (Image.asset(
                  'assets/icons/groceries.JPG',
                  height: 70,
                  width: 60,
                )),
                'Groceries & \n   Supplies'),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put your items in a `GridView`, specifically, a `GridView.count` to specify a number of items per row:

```dart
GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 5,
  children: [
    ...
  ],
),
```

Comment: As an aside, include some code and try to be precise when describing the desired outcome. I had to guess what you were going for when writing my answer :P